# JQuery - IE 6,7 Opacity does not work

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, opacity

Yeah some people on the web have the same problem.. but there was no real answer on this. The JQuery devs say that IE 6,7,8 is supportet but I really need the opacity animation to get work.

But that does not work.. I need a solution for the IE 6,7.
I heared that the alpha filter of the ie is a good thing.. but please give me some advice my friends.

nya - here some codez for a non-meta discussion:

```
$('#video').click(function() {
    $button = $(this);
    if ( clickedv === 0){
    if( !$button.hasClass( 'disabled' ) ) {
        $button.addClass( 'disabled' );
    clickedv = 1;
    $('#video').animate({width: 0, height: 0, top: 52, left: 311},0);
       $('.flv').animate({left: 19, opacity: '1'},0).css('display', 'inline');
       $('galleria-thumbnails').animate({opacity: '0.3!important'},0);
        $('.close').animate({opacity: '1'},0,

        function() { $button.removeClass('disabled') });

    } 
    }

});

$('.close').click(function() {
    $button = $(this);

    if ( clickedv == 1){
    if( !$button.hasClass( 'disabled' ) ) {
        $button.addClass( 'disabled' );
    clickedv = 0;
    $('#video').animate({width: 164, height: 29, top: 498, marginLeft: 262},0);
       $('.flv').animate({left: 2222, opacity: '0'},0).css('display', 'none');
        $('.close').animate({opacity: '0'},0,
        function() { $button.removeClass('disabled') });

    } 
    }

});
```

Comment: This already works in IE 6, 7, 8....what the issue?

Comment: @Mr. - I know so, we do it every day...what's your issue? :)

Comment: Could you post some code samples? It should be more productive than meta-discussion :-)

Comment: jQuery is built cross browser - it will use the appropriate methods to reduce your opacity - you don't need to specify browser specific css declarations within a jQuery function (or at least - you don't in this case). Does this code work in any browser? What specifically is the issue (does the function fire without any errors and just not change the opacity)? Finally - why do you have an !important statement in your animate function??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't support `opacity` as a CSS style.

It does have alternative methods for doing opacity via stylesheets, using the IE-specific `filter` style, but that isn't the answer I'd recommend in your case -- the CSS can get very ugly when you have to support several different syntax variants, and even worse if you're changing it dynamically in javascript.

What you need to do is use jQuery's fade methods instead. This will give you good cross browser compatible animated transparency effects. See the [jQuery manual pages for more info](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/).

Comment: fadeTo() is what I need! Thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 1):

From my [test](http://jsbin.com/ajoci3/2/edit) ie8 doesn't like having a !important tag in the jquery animate statement while chrome seems happy with it. Does it work if you remove this?

Answer (score 0):

IE uses the alpha filter, so you need to do two styles for opacity.

```
opacity:0.3; filter:alpha(opacity=30);
```

some older versions of Mozilla need

```
-moz-opacity:0.3;
```

you can also try

```
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=30)
```